# Как организованы View-классы?

Tags: php, mvc

Если модель отработала успешно - вызываем view и передаём в неё данные:

```
if($model->addData()){
 return $view->congratulations($result);
}
```

Вопрос: что писать внутри метода congratulations во view?

Можно код прям там писать, например:

```
public function congratulations()
{
    return ''
        .'<div>'
            .'<h1>'.$this->data->date.' - '.$this->data->title.'</h1>'
            .'<p>'.$this->data->text.'</p>'
        .'</div>';
}
```

Но вьюшек много, если где-то изменится html-код или шаблон то адски тяжело всё поменять будет.

Корректно ли во view подтягивать статические файлы с html? Например:

```
public function congratulations()
{
    $html = '';
    $html .= include_once('header.php');
    $html .= include_once('menu.php');

    foreach ($this->data as $key => $item) {
        $html .= $this->item($item);
    }

    $html .= include_once('footer.php');

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Меня всегда интересловало, почему меню инклюдится отдельно от хидера.

Comment: @Ипатьев потому что шапка у проекта одна, и несколько разделов в личном кабинете. Если пользователь переходит из раздела в раздел у него меняется меню. В Балансе например: платежи, история. В делах: календарь, планер и т.д. Т.е. menu в данном случае это подменю на самом деле